# dplyr summarize with subtotals

Tags: r, dplyr, summary, subtotal

One of the great things about pivot tables in excel is that they provide subtotals automatically.  First, I would like to know if there is anything already created within dplyr that can accomplish this.  If not, what is the easiest way to achieve it?

In the example below, I show the mean displacement by number of cylinders and carburetors.  For each group of cylinders (4,6,8), I'd like to see the mean displacement for the group (or total displacement, or any other summary statistic).

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>% group_by(cyl,carb) %>% summarize(mean(disp))

  cyl carb mean(disp)
1   4    1      91.38
2   4    2     116.60
3   6    1     241.50
4   6    4     163.80
5   6    6     145.00
6   8    2     345.50
7   8    3     275.80
8   8    4     405.50
9   8    8     301.00
```

Comment: The example works.  What exactly is your question?

Comment: `cummean()`?  I still don't get the question.  Oh well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**data.table** It's very clunky, but this is one way:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(mtcars)
rbind(
  DT[,.(mean(disp)),          by=.(cyl,carb)],
  DT[,.(mean(disp), carb=NA), by=.(cyl) ],
  DT[,.(mean(disp), cyl=NA),  by=.(carb)]
)[order(cyl,carb)]
```

This gives

```
    cyl carb       V1
 1:   4    1  91.3800
 2:   4    2 116.6000
 3:   4   NA 105.1364
 4:   6    1 241.5000
 5:   6    4 163.8000
 6:   6    6 145.0000
 7:   6   NA 183.3143
 8:   8    2 345.5000
 9:   8    3 275.8000
10:   8    4 405.5000
11:   8    8 301.0000
12:   8   NA 353.1000
13:  NA    1 134.2714
14:  NA    2 208.1600
15:  NA    3 275.8000
16:  NA    4 308.8200
17:  NA    6 145.0000
18:  NA    8 301.0000
```

I'd rather see results in something like an R `table`, but don't know of any functions for that.

---

**dplyr** @akrun found this analogous code

```
bind_rows(
  mtcars %>% 
    group_by(cyl, carb) %>% 
    summarise(Mean= mean(disp)), 
  mtcars %>% 
    group_by(cyl) %>% 
    summarise(carb=NA, Mean=mean(disp)), 
  mtcars %>% 
    group_by(carb) %>% 
    summarise(cyl=NA, Mean=mean(disp))
) %>% arrange(cyl, carb)
```

We could wrap the repeat operations in a function

```
library(lazyeval)
f1 <- function(df, grp, Var, func){
  FUN <- match.fun(func)
   df %>% 
     group_by_(.dots=grp) %>%
     summarise_(interp(~FUN(v), v=as.name(Var)))
  }

 m1 <- f1(mtcars, c('carb', 'cyl'), 'disp', 'mean')
 m2 <- f1(mtcars, 'carb', 'disp', 'mean')
 m3 <- f1(mtcars, 'cyl', 'disp', 'mean')

 bind_rows(list(m1, m2, m3)) %>%
              arrange(cyl, carb) %>%
              rename(Mean=`FUN(disp)`)
   carb cyl     Mean
1     1   4  91.3800
2     2   4 116.6000
3    NA   4 105.1364
4     1   6 241.5000
5     4   6 163.8000
6     6   6 145.0000
7    NA   6 183.3143
8     2   8 345.5000
9     3   8 275.8000
10    4   8 405.5000
11    8   8 301.0000
12   NA   8 353.1000
13    1  NA 134.2714
14    2  NA 208.1600
15    3  NA 275.8000
16    4  NA 308.8200
17    6  NA 145.0000
18    8  NA 301.0000
```

---

Either option can be made a little less ugly with data.table's `rbindlist` with `fill`:

```
rbindlist(list(
  mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% summarise(mean(disp)),
  mtcars %>% group_by(carb) %>% summarise(mean(disp)),
  mtcars %>% group_by(cyl,carb) %>% summarise(mean(disp))
),fill=TRUE) %>% arrange(cyl,carb)

rbindlist(list(
  DT[,mean(disp),by=.(cyl,carb)],
  DT[,mean(disp),by=.(cyl)],
  DT[,mean(disp),by=.(carb)]
),fill=TRUE)[order(cyl,carb)]
```

Comment: I actually learned a lot from all the answers posted, but this one gets almost exactly what I'm looking for.  Now if we could just talk @hadley into making this a streamlined option for summarize()!

Comment: @KyleWard I agree that a shortcut is badly needed here. I'd want one for LegalizeIt's answer even more, as I like seeing marginal computations on actual margins. Surprised there's no function for this already.

Comment: @KyleWard I just created an issue for this in my [`nhtsHelper`](https://github.com/gregmacfarlane/nhtsHelper/issues/1) package.

Answer (score 9):

Also possible by simply joining the two group results:

```
cyl_carb <- mtcars %>% group_by(cyl,carb) %>% summarize(mean(disp))
cyl <- mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% summarize(mean(disp))
joined <- full_join(cyl_carb, cyl)
result <- arrange(joined, cyl)
result
```

gives:

```
Source: local data frame [12 x 3]
Groups: cyl [3]

     cyl  carb mean(disp)
   (dbl) (dbl)      (dbl)
1      4     1    91.3800
2      4     2   116.6000
3      4    NA   105.1364
4      6     1   241.5000
5      6     4   163.8000
6      6     6   145.0000
7      6    NA   183.3143
8      8     2   345.5000
9      8     3   275.8000
10     8     4   405.5000
11     8     8   301.0000
12     8    NA   353.1000
```

or with an additional column:

```
cyl_carb <- mtcars %>% group_by(cyl,carb) %>% summarize(mean(disp))
cyl <- mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% summarize(mean.cyl = mean(disp))
joined <- full_join(cyl_carb, cyl)
joined
```

gives:

```
Source: local data frame [9 x 4]
Groups: cyl [?]

    cyl  carb mean(disp) mean.cyl
  (dbl) (dbl)      (dbl)    (dbl)
1     4     1      91.38 105.1364
2     4     2     116.60 105.1364
3     6     1     241.50 183.3143
4     6     4     163.80 183.3143
5     6     6     145.00 183.3143
6     8     2     345.50 353.1000
7     8     3     275.80 353.1000
8     8     4     405.50 353.1000
9     8     8     301.00 353.1000
```

Comment: That is the best so far! Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Something similar to `table` with `addmargins` (although actually a `data.frame`)

```
library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)
out <- bind_cols(
    mtcars %>% group_by(cyl, carb) %>%
      summarise(mu = mean(disp)) %>%
      dcast(cyl ~ carb),
    (mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% summarise(Total=mean(disp)))[,2]
)

margin <- t((mtcars %>% group_by(carb) %>% summarise(Total=mean(disp)))[,2])
rbind(out, c(NA, margin, mean(mtcars$disp))) %>%
  `rownames<-`(c(paste("cyl", c(4,6,8)), "Total"))  # add some row names
#      cyl        1      2     3      4   6   8    Total
# cyl 4   4  91.3800 116.60    NA     NA  NA  NA 105.1364
# cyl 6   6 241.5000     NA    NA 163.80 145  NA 183.3143
# cyl 8   8       NA 345.50 275.8 405.50  NA 301 353.1000
# Total  NA 134.2714 208.16 275.8 308.82 145 301 230.7219
```

The bottom row is the column wise margins, columns named 1:8 are carbs, and Total is the rowwise margins.

Comment: Nice, this is the formatting I'd want to see. Are your `[,2]`s just a shortcut because you don't like column names and `select`?

Comment: yea, is there a simple way to droup group names?

Comment: I think `select` is for that: `mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% summarise(Total=mean(disp)) %>% select(-cyl)` I don't know a way of saying "not the group name" though (as opposed to retyping the name). You could do `select(-1)`, which may be more idiomatic for dplyr...not sure about that.

Comment: Maybe `margin <- mtcars %>% group_by(carb) %>% summarise(Total = mean(disp)) %>% .$Total` ?

Comment: @StevenBeaupré Yes! that's perfect

Answer (score 4):

Here is a simple one-liner creating margins within a data_frame:

```
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)

# Margins without labels
mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl,carb) %>% 
  summarize(Mean_Disp=mean(disp)) %>% 
  do(plyr::rbind.fill(., data_frame(cyl=first(.$cyl), Mean_Disp=sum(.$Mean_Disp, na.rm=T))))
```

output:

```
Source: local data frame [12 x 3]
Groups: cyl [3]

     cyl  carb Mean_Disp
   <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>
1      4     1     91.38
2      4     2    116.60
3      4    NA    207.98
4      6     1    241.50
5      6     4    163.80
6      6     6    145.00
7      6    NA    550.30
8      8     2    345.50
9      8     3    275.80
10     8     4    405.50
11     8     8    301.00
12     8    NA   1327.80
```

You may also add labels for the summary statistics like:

```
mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl,carb) %>% 
  summarize(Mean_Disp=mean(disp)) %>% 
  do(plyr::rbind.fill(., data_frame(cyl=first(.$cyl), carb=c("Total", "Mean"), Mean_Disp=c(sum(.$Mean_Disp, na.rm=T), mean(.$Mean_Disp, na.rm=T)))))
```

output:

```
Source: local data frame [15 x 3]
Groups: cyl [3]

     cyl  carb Mean_Disp
   <dbl> <chr>     <dbl>
1      4     1     91.38
2      4     2    116.60
3      4 Total    207.98
4      4  Mean    103.99
5      6     1    241.50
6      6     4    163.80
7      6     6    145.00
8      6 Total    550.30
9      6  Mean    183.43
10     8     2    345.50
11     8     3    275.80
12     8     4    405.50
13     8     8    301.00
14     8 Total   1327.80
15     8  Mean    331.95
```

Answer (score 3):

With `data.table` version above `v1.11`

```r
library(data.table)

cubed <- cube(
  as.data.table(mtcars),
  .(`mean(disp)` = mean(disp)),
  by = c("cyl", "carb")
)
#>     cyl carb mean(disp)
#>  1:   6    4   163.8000
#>  2:   4    1    91.3800
#>  3:   6    1   241.5000
#>  4:   8    2   345.5000
#>  5:   8    4   405.5000
#>  6:   4    2   116.6000
#>  7:   8    3   275.8000
#>  8:   6    6   145.0000
#>  9:   8    8   301.0000
#> 10:   6   NA   183.3143
#> 11:   4   NA   105.1364
#> 12:   8   NA   353.1000
#> 13:  NA    4   308.8200
#> 14:  NA    1   134.2714
#> 15:  NA    2   208.1600
#> 16:  NA    3   275.8000
#> 17:  NA    6   145.0000
#> 18:  NA    8   301.0000
#> 19:  NA   NA   230.7219
```

```
res <- dcast(
  cubed, 
  cyl ~ carb,  
  value.var = "mean(disp)"
)
#>    cyl       NA        1      2     3      4   6   8
#> 1:  NA 230.7219 134.2714 208.16 275.8 308.82 145 301
#> 2:   4 105.1364  91.3800 116.60    NA     NA  NA  NA
#> 3:   6 183.3143 241.5000     NA    NA 163.80 145  NA
#> 4:   8 353.1000       NA 345.50 275.8 405.50  NA 301
```

<sup>Created on 2020-02-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Source: https://jozef.io/r912-datatable-grouping-sets/

---

```
library(kableExtra)

options(knitr.kable.NA = "")

res <- as.data.frame(res)
names(res)[2] <- "overall"
res[1, 1] <- "overall"
x <- kable(res, "html") 
x <- kable_styling(x, "striped") 
add_header_above(x, c(" " = 1, "carb" = ncol(res) - 1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I know that this may not be a very elegant solution, but I hope it helps anyway:

```
p <-mtcars %>% group_by(cyl,carb) 
p$cyl <- as.factor(p$cyl)
average_disp <- sapply(1:length(levels(p$cyl)), function(x)mean(subset(p,p$cyl==levels(p$cyl)[x])$disp))
df <- data.frame(levels(p$cyl),average_disp)
colnames(df)[1]<-"cyl"

#> df
#  cyl average_disp
#1   4     105.1364
#2   6     183.3143
#3   8     353.1000
```

(Edit: After a minor modification in the definition of `p` this now yields the same results as @Frank's and @akrun's solution)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this wrapper around `ddply`, which applies `ddply` for each possible margin and `rbinds` the results with its usual output.

To marginalize over all grouping factors:

```
mtcars %>% ddplym(.variables = .(cyl, carb), .fun = summarise, mean(disp))
```

To marginalize over `carb` only:

```
mtcars %>% ddplym(
  .variables = .(carb),
  .fun = function(data) data %>% group_by(cyl) %>% summarise(mean(disp)))
```

---

Wrapper:

```
require(plyr)
require(dplyr)

ddplym <- function(.data, .variables, .fun, ..., .margin = TRUE, .margin_name = '(all)') {
  if (.margin) {
    df <- .ddplym(.data, .variables, .fun, ..., .margin_name = .margin_name)
  } else {
    df <- ddply(.data, .variables, .fun, ...)
    if (.variables %>% length == 0) {
      df$.id <- NULL
    }
  }

  return(df)
}

.ddplym <- function(.data,
                    .variables,
                    .fun,
                    ...,
                    .margin_name = '(all)'
) {

  .variables <- as.quoted(.variables)

  n <- length(.variables)

  var_combn_idx <- lapply(0:n, function(x) {
    combn(1:n, n - x) %>% alply(2, c)
  }) %>%
    unlist(recursive = FALSE, use.names = FALSE)

  data_list <- lapply(var_combn_idx, function(x) {
    data <- ddply(.data, .variables[x], .fun, ...)

    # drop '.id' column created when no variables to split by specified
    if (!length(.variables[x]))
      data <- data[, -1, drop = FALSE]

    return(data)
  })

  # workaround for NULL .variables
  if (unlist(.variables) %>% is.null && names(.variables) %>% is.null) {
    data_list <- data_list[1]
  } else if (unlist(.variables) %>% is.null) {
    data_list <- data_list[2]
  }

  if (length(data_list) > 1) {
    data_list <- lapply(data_list, function(data)
      rbind_pre(
        data = data,
        colnames = colnames(data_list[[1]]),
        fill = .margin_name
      )) 
  }

  Reduce(rbind, data_list)
}

rbind_pre <- function(data, colnames, fill = NA) {
  colnames_fill <- setdiff(colnames, colnames(data))
  data_fill <- matrix(fill,
                      nrow = nrow(data),
                      ncol = length(colnames_fill)) %>%
    as.data.frame %>% setNames(colnames_fill)
  cbind(data, data_fill)[, colnames]
}
```

Comment: This only works on data frames with all numeric variables

Answer (score 0):

Sharing my approach to this (if its helpful at all). This approach allows for customised sub-totals and totals to be added very easily.

```
data = data.frame( thing1=sprintf("group %i",trunc(runif(200,0,5))),
                   thing2=sprintf("type %i",trunc(runif(200,0,5))),
                   value=rnorm(200,0,1) )
data %>%
  group_by( thing1, thing2 ) %>% 
  summarise( sum=sum(value),
             count=n() ) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  bind_rows(.,
            identity(.) %>%
              group_by(thing1) %>%
              summarise( aggregation="sub total",
                         sum=sum(sum),
                         count=sum(count) ) %>%
              ungroup(),
            identity(.) %>%
              summarise( aggregation="total",
                         sum=sum(sum),
                         count=sum(count) ) %>%
              ungroup() ) %>%
  arrange( thing1, thing2, aggregation ) %>%
  select( aggregation, everything() )
```

Answer (score 0):

Having tried long and hard for very similar issues, I have found that `data.table` offers the simplest and fastest solution which fits exactly this purpose

```
data.table::cube(
             data.table::as.data.table(mtcars),
             .(mean_disp = mean(disp)),
             by = c("cyl","carb"))

   cyl carb mean_disp
 1:   6    4  163.8000
 2:   4    1   91.3800
 3:   6    1  241.5000
 4:   8    2  345.5000
 5:   8    4  405.5000
 6:   4    2  116.6000
 7:   8    3  275.8000
 8:   6    6  145.0000
 9:   8    8  301.0000
10:   6   NA  183.3143
11:   4   NA  105.1364
12:   8   NA  353.1000
13:  NA    4  308.8200
14:  NA    1  134.2714
15:  NA    2  208.1600
16:  NA    3  275.8000
17:  NA    6  145.0000
18:  NA    8  301.0000
19:  NA   NA  230.7219
```

The `NA` entries are the subtotals you are looking for; for instance in row 10 the `183.31` result is the mean for all 6 cylinders. The last row with double `NA` is the one with the overall mean.

From there, you can easily wrap the result with `as_tibble()` to jump back into the `dplyr` semantics world.

Comment: Just noticed Aurele's comments which is the same as mine but precedes me by a few months! Credit to Aurele

Answer (score 0):

Having had this same issue, I'm working on a function to hopefully address this (see https://github.com/jrf1111/TCCD/blob/dev/R/with_subtotals.R).  It's still in its development phase, but it does exactly what you're looking for.

```
mtcars %>% 
group_by(cyl, carb) %>% 
with_subtotals() %>% 
summarize(mean(disp))

# A tibble: 19 x 3
# Groups:   cyl [5]
   cyl      carb     `mean(disp)`
   <chr>    <chr>           <dbl>
 1 4        1                91.4
 2 4        2               117. 
 3 4        subtotal        105. 
 4 6        1               242. 
 5 6        4               164. 
 6 6        6               145  
 7 6        subtotal        183. 
 8 8        2               346. 
 9 8        3               276. 
10 8        4               406. 
11 8        8               301  
12 8        subtotal        353. 
13 subtotal 1               134. 
14 subtotal 2               208. 
15 subtotal 3               276. 
16 subtotal 4               309. 
17 subtotal 6               145  
18 subtotal 8               301  
19 total    total           231.
```