# SQL Syntax in R programming

Tags: sql, r

I have the below data set.

```
QTR MONTHS  SALES
Q1  JAN     100
Q1  FEB     200
Q2  MAY     300
Q2  JUN     400
```

I want to see something like this

```
Row Labels  JAN FEB MAY JUN Grand Total
Q1          100 200         300
Q2                  300 400 700
Grand Total 100 200 300 400 1000
```

I want to write an SQL query in R.

Comment: Do you want to using SQL in R? Or do you want to get that output. You don't need to do use SQL in R to get that output...

Comment: Hi dason, I can get it by using Summarise. But I would like to switch to SQL completely :).

Comment: Now we know what you want to achieve. I can't tell whether this makes sense, but clearly your post does not contain a _question_. Furthermore, you didn't include any hints on how you want to solve problem. StackOverflow works best if the questioners do a little research on their own and can include that research in their questions...

Comment: `mout <- reshape(mdat, idvar = "QTR", timevar = "MONTHS", direction = "wide"); mout$total <- rowSums(mout[,-1], na.rm = T)`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31164350/dplyr-summarize-with-subtotals

Comment: There really isn't a very good way to do this in SQL that I'm aware of.  Some variants of SQL have an `unpivot` command that makes this kind of transformation only moderately painful.  This is a situation where, unless you're really determined to keep the operations in the database, it's probably easier to do it in R.

Comment: Hi, can somebody tell me how to do it R?

Answer (score 0):

you can use a library called sqldf to do sql in R.

```
library(sqldf)

data(titanic3, package="PASWR")

df <- sqldf(`select age from titanic3 where age != "NA"`)

head(df)
```