# Summarize data at different aggregate levels - R and tidyverse

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

I'm creating a bunch of basic status reports and one of things I'm finding tedious is adding a total row to all my tables. I'm currently using the Tidyverse approach and this is an example of my current code. What I'm looking for is an option to have a few different levels included by default.

```
#load into RStudio viewer (not required)
iris = iris

#summary at the group level
summary_grouped = iris %>% 
       group_by(Species) %>%
       summarize(mean_s_length = mean(Sepal.Length),
                 max_s_width = max(Sepal.Width))

#summary at the overall level
summary_overall = iris %>% 
  summarize(mean_s_length = mean(Sepal.Length),
            max_s_width = max(Sepal.Width)) %>%
  mutate(Species = "Overall")

#append results for report       
summary_table = rbind(summary_grouped, summary_overall)
```

Doing this multiple times over is very tedious. I kind of want:

```
summary_overall = iris %>% 
       group_by(Species, total = TRUE) %>%
       summarize(mean_s_length = mean(Sepal.Length),
                 max_s_width = max(Sepal.Width))
```

FYI - if you're familiar with SAS I'm looking for the same type of functionality available via a class, ways or types statements in proc means that let me control the level of summarization and get multiple levels in one call.

Any help is appreciated. I know I can create my own function, but was hoping there is something that already exists. I would also prefer to stick with the tidyverse style of programming though I'm not set on that.

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31164350/324364) for some ideas, but pretty much everything I've ever seen is quite manual and clunky.

Comment: The `janitor` and `pivottabler` packages offer some built-in approaches. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pivottabler/vignettes/v01-introduction.html

Comment: grouping sets are not likely to be native in dplyr https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/236 unfortunately

Comment: If the data is not massive, you could literally bind everything on the bottom again and use it as the total summary - `iris %>%
    bind_rows(., mutate(iris, Species="all")) ...` - a waste of memory but it will avoid needing multiple calls.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another alternative:

```r
library(tidyverse)  

iris %>% 
  mutate_at("Species", as.character) %>%
  list(group_by(.,Species), .) %>%
  map(~summarize(.,mean_s_length = mean(Sepal.Length),
                 max_s_width = max(Sepal.Width))) %>%
  bind_rows() %>%
  replace_na(list(Species="Overall"))
#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#>   Species    mean_s_length max_s_width
#>   <chr>              <dbl>       <dbl>
#> 1 setosa              5.01         4.4
#> 2 versicolor          5.94         3.4
#> 3 virginica           6.59         3.8
#> 4 Overall             5.84         4.4
```

Answer (score 3):

You can write a function which does the same `summarize` on an `ungroup`ed tibble and rbinds that to the end.

```
summarize2 <- function(df, ...){
 bind_rows(summarise(df, ...), summarize(ungroup(df), ...))
}

iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>%
  summarize2(
    mean_s_length = mean(Sepal.Length),
    max_s_width = max(Sepal.Width)
  )

# # A tibble: 4 x 3
#   Species    mean_s_length max_s_width
#   <fct>              <dbl>       <dbl>
# 1 setosa              5.01         4.4
# 2 versicolor          5.94         3.4
# 3 virginica           6.59         3.8
# 4 NA                  5.84         4.4
```

You could add some logic for what the "Overall" groups should be named if you want

```
summarize2 <- function(df, ...){
  s1 <- summarise(df, ...)
  s2 <- summarize(ungroup(df), ...)
  for(v in group_vars(s1)){
    if(is.factor(s1[[v]]))
      s1[[v]] <- as.character(s1[[v]])
    if(is.character(s1[[v]])) 
     s2[[v]] <- 'Overall'
    else if(is.numeric(s1[[v]])) 
     s2[[v]] <- -Inf
  }
  bind_rows(s1, s2)
}


iris %>% 
  group_by(Species, g = Petal.Length %/% 1) %>%
  summarize2(
    mean_s_length = mean(Sepal.Length),
    max_s_width = max(Sepal.Width)
  )

# # Groups:   Species [4]
#   Species        g mean_s_length max_s_width
#   <chr>      <dbl>         <dbl>       <dbl>
# 1 setosa         1          5.01         4.4
# 2 versicolor     3          5.35         2.9
# 3 versicolor     4          6.09         3.4
# 4 versicolor     5          6.35         3  
# 5 virginica      4          5.85         3  
# 6 virginica      5          6.44         3.4
# 7 virginica      6          7.43         3.8
# 8 Overall     -Inf          5.84         4.4
```

Answer (score 2):

```r
library(dplyr)

iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>%
  summarize(mean_s_length = mean(Sepal.Length),
            max_s_width = max(Sepal.Width)) %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(Species), as.character) %>% 
  {rbind(.,c("Overal",mean(.$mean_s_length),max(.$max_s_width)))} %>%
  mutate_at(vars(-Species), as.double) %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(Species), as.factor)
#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#>   Species    mean_s_length max_s_width
#>   <fct>              <dbl>       <dbl>
#> 1 setosa              5.01         4.4
#> 2 versicolor          5.94         3.4
#> 3 virginica           6.59         3.8
#> 4 Overal              5.84         4.4
```

<sup>Created on 2019-06-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

One way, also tedious but in one longer pipe, is to put the second summarise instructions in `bind_rows`.
The `as.character` call avoids a warning:

> Warning messages:
>   1: In bind_rows_(x, .id) :
>     binding factor and character vector, coercing into character vector
>   2: In bind_rows_(x, .id) :
>     binding character and factor vector, coercing into character vector

```
library(tidyverse)

summary_grouped <- iris %>% 
  mutate(Species = as.character(Species)) %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  summarize(mean_s_length = mean(Sepal.Length),
            max_s_width = max(Sepal.Width)) %>%
  bind_rows(iris %>% 
              summarize(mean_s_length = mean(Sepal.Length),
                        max_s_width = max(Sepal.Width)) %>%
              mutate(Species = "Overall"))
## A tibble: 4 x 3
#  Species    mean_s_length max_s_width
#  <chr>              <dbl>       <dbl>
#1 setosa              5.01         4.4
#2 versicolor          5.94         3.4
#3 virginica           6.59         3.8
#4 Overall             5.84         4.4
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this:

As you want to perform different operations on the same input (`iris`), best to `map` over the different summary functions and apply to the data. 
`map_dfr` combines the list outputs using `bind_rows`

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

pipe <- . %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  summarize(
    mean_s_length = mean(Sepal.Length),
    max_s_width   = max(Sepal.Width))

map_dfr(
  list(pipe, . %>% mutate(Species = "Overall") %>% pipe),
  exec, 
  iris)
#> Warning in bind_rows_(x, .id): binding factor and character vector,
#> coercing into character vector
#> Warning in bind_rows_(x, .id): binding character and factor vector,
#> coercing into character vector
#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#>   Species    mean_s_length max_s_width
#>   <chr>              <dbl>       <dbl>
#> 1 setosa              5.01         4.4
#> 2 versicolor          5.94         3.4
#> 3 virginica           6.59         3.8
#> 4 Overall             5.84         4.4
```

Answer (score 2):

Solution where you need to apply wanted function only once on a double dataset:

```
library(tidyverse)
iris %>%
  rbind(mutate(., Species = "Overall")) %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  summarize(
    mean_s_length = mean(Sepal.Length),
    max_s_width = max(Sepal.Width)
  )

# A tibble: 4 x 3
  Species    mean_s_length max_s_width
  <chr>              <dbl>       <dbl>
1 Overall             5.84         4.4
2 setosa              5.01         4.4
3 versicolor          5.94         3.4
4 virginica           6.59         3.8
```

Trick is to pass original dataset with a new group ID (ie `Species`): `mutate(iris, Species = "Overall")`

Comment: This duplicates the data set overall, essentially adding an Overall category? This works for the use case shown, but is slightly more complex if I have more than one grouping variable. Thanks!